# Can you use `this` inside the `ready` callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I was doing some tutorials online, and I set up my JavaScript file thusly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).keydown(function(key){ });    
});
```

The code in the example was like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(key){ });    
});
```

Is there a difference with this code? Will it do the same thing?

Comment: Did you try it and see?

Comment: Yeah both do the same thing. `this` references the `document` node inside the `ready` handler. http://jsbin.com/ucihup/1/edit

Comment: Both will work just fine, but as the `document` is always available and is cheap to look up (at least I think it is), using the `this` keyword isn't really common practice (as far as I know), probably because the perfomance gain is minimal while the chance of mixing up scope and using the wrong `this` could be an issue in more complicated code.

Comment: @Mathletics I did try it, but the tutorial I was using didn't work with the "wrong" input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both do the same thing `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/Tks5L/7/

Inside your document.ready `$(this)` is same as `$(document)` as `this` refers to current `document`

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use $this at ready state, because you are providing "document" as operator.
If you preview your console when launching

```
$(document).ready(function(){ console.log(this); });
```

you should notice that you receive document back the same as calling just "document".

Also, I just want to point out an easier way:

```
$(function(){ console.log(this); });
```

will return document as well.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those statements do the same thing. http://jsfiddle.net/dJevP/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).keydown(function(key){
        alert("this");
    });    
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(key){
        alert("document");
    });    
});
```